# Spring Integration with ActiveMQ : Get notification when queue has no more pending messages

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am working with spring integration with ActiveMQ. I have requirement to do some process when my queue is empty (no more pending messages). I have achieved that something like this,

```
package my.com.spring.integration;

public class MyListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

        @Override protected void messageReceived(Object invoker, Session session) {
            // I mark lastMessageReceived time here 
            super.messageReceived(invoker, session);
        }

        @Override protected void noMessageReceived(Object invoker, Session session) {
            // I wait for 1 minute from last message messageReceived and after 
            // that I consider that queue has no more messages now and
            // I start my stuff
            super.noMessageReceived(invoker, session);
        }
    }
```

And my spring xml looks like this,

```
<bean id="my.jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=250&jms.useAsyncSend=true" />
    <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="my.jms.cachedConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
    p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="my.jmsConnectionFactory"
    p:sessionCacheSize="10" p:reconnectOnException="true" />

 <bean id="myListenerContainer "
        class="my.com.spring.integration.MyListenerContainer ">
        <property name="connectionFactory"
            ref="my.jms.cachedConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="myQ" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myMessageListener"
        class="org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener" />

    <bean id="myJmsEndpoint"
        class="org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="myListenerContainer" />
        <constructor-arg ref="myMessageListener" />
        <property name="outputChannel" ref="myConsumerChannel" />
    </bean>
```

Everything works fine as of yet. I am getting notification when queue is empty and I am able to do my desired stuff.

**The Question :** Is there **any other reason** for not to receive messages anymore apart from the queue being empty? Like if any exception occurs within spring code execution, what happens?  Is this proper way for to implement my purpose? If no, how can I improve this?

Answer (score 0):

`noMessageReceived` is called only when there is not message received and not when an exception is thrown.

This is means that the DMLC do not received a message but keep in mind that your purpose is good only if you have only one DMLC.

Because AMQ dispatches a lot of messages (in your case `jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=250`) to each consumer and the dispatched messages are in treatment on each consumer and maybe if it disconnects without acknowledging them the messages remains available to be dispatched to another consumer.

take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

If you want to be sure to have informations from the broker about the queue you can use JMX to get the size or the number of dispatched messages.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.BrokerViewMBean;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.QueueViewMBean;

public class JMXGetDestinationInfos {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
        Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap<>();
        String[] creds = { "admin", "admin" };
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
        MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

        ObjectName activeMq = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");

        BrokerViewMBean mbean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, activeMq, BrokerViewMBean.class,
                true);
        for (ObjectName name : mbean.getQueues()) {
            if (("myQ".equals(name.getKeyProperty("destinationName")))) {
                QueueViewMBean queueMbean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, name,
                        QueueViewMBean.class, true);
                // ="Number of messages in the destination which are yet to be
                // consumed. Potentially dispatched but unacknowledged.")
                System.out.println(queueMbean.getQueueSize());
                // Returns the number of messages that have been delivered
                // (potentially not acknowledged) to consumers.
                System.out.println(queueMbean.getDispatchCount());
            }
        }
    }
}
```